# Subversion post-commit hook

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

I am trying to get SVN to copy files to my htdocs folder on commit. Here is what I have so far in my post-commit.bat:

```
"C:\subversion\bin\svn.exe" update "C:\apache\apache2.2\htdocs"
```

When I look at the log files created by the hook I get the following line:

```
Skipped 'C:\Apache\Apache2.2\htdocs'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

No matter what directory I choose as a destination, I get the same error.

I am running SVN 1.6.4, Tortoise 1.6.8, Apache 2.2, WinXP SP3

I am not using username and password because there is no security set up on the SVN repository. It's just me developing.

Thanks

Comment: maybe turn on verbose option, you may get with this some information about why this was skipped

Comment: Is `htdocs` a working copy? Are you 100% sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this with a folder that isn't a working copy:

```
C:\Temp>md blah

C:\Temp>svn up blah
Skipped 'blah'

C:\Temp>
```

Are you sure there's a working copy at `C:\apache\apache2.2\htdocs`? You first need to checkout into that folder before you can update into it.
Can you do this:

```
cd C:\apache\apache2.2\htdocs
svn up
```

If this doesn't work for you, it certainly won't for the server.

Comment: I was unaware that the destination had to be a working copy. I fixed that and it works great now. Thanks SBI and Pekka too.

Answer (score 0):

Try use checkout option (you must add link to repository too)